# display complex find results in a cakephp3 debug

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I did a query on with associated data. It does work and displays all the data (given below).

My debug output contains a  lot of extra fieldsi in []brackets, so how do I limit this to only the required data from the select  and have no extra fields in [] brackets display?

Also this the optimum way to get such associated data in cakephp3? as I am used to cakephp2.There is a lot less code in cakephp3 for a find over many tables but I did prefer the cakephp2  parameters. I am used to using joins for the find and conditions for the where but cakephp3 doesnt need the join code in the find.

```
$query3 = $this->Bookmarks->find()
          ->contain(['Users'])
          ->select(['bookmarks.id','bookmarks.title','users.id'])      
          ->where(['bookmarks.id' => 1])  ;    

        $query3->matching('Tags', function ($q) {

             return $q
                ->select(['tags.id']) 
                ->where(['Tags.title like' => '%tes%']);
            });


            foreach ( $query3 as $row) {
                  debug($row);
              }

//bookmarks model
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('bookmarks');


        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Tags', [
            'foreignKey' => 'bookmark_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'joinTable' => 'bookmarks_tags'
        ]);
    }


'bookmarks' => [
    'id' => '1',
    'title' => 'kmkl'
],
'users' => [
    'id' => '1'
],
'tags' => [
    'id' => '1'
],
'[new]' => false,
'[accessible]' => [
    '*' => true
],
'[dirty]' => [],
'[original]' => [],
'[virtual]' => [],
'[errors]' => [],
'[invalid]' => [],
'[repository]' => 'Bookmarks'
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

Comment: try ```$query3->toArray();```  and then loop / debug results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get just an array from a query object, use `toArray`

**Change**

```
$query3 = $this->Bookmarks->find()
          ->contain(['Users'])
          ->select(['bookmarks.id','bookmarks.title','users.id'])      
          ->where(['bookmarks.id' => 1]);
```

**TO**

```
$query3 = $this->Bookmarks->find()
          ->contain(['Users'])
          ->select(['bookmarks.id','bookmarks.title','users.id'])      
          ->where(['bookmarks.id' => 1])
          ->toArray();  // <--
```